# (with example) Why is KMP string matching O(n). Shouldn't it be O(n*m)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, string-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

Why is KMP O(n + m)?

I know this question has probably been asked a million times on here but I haven't find a solution that convinced me/I understood or a question that matched my example.

```
/**
 * KMP algorithm of pattern matching.
 */
public boolean KMP(char []text, char []pattern){

    int lps[] = computeTemporaryArray(pattern);
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i < text.length && j < pattern.length){
        if(text[i] == pattern[j]){
            i++;
            j++;
        }else{
            if(j!=0){
                j = lps[j-1];
            }else{
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(j == pattern.length){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

n = size of text
m = size of pattern

I know why its + m, thats the runtime it takes to create the lsp array to do lookups. I'm not sure why the code I passed above is O(n).

I see that above "i" always progresses forwards EXCEPT when it doesn't match and j!= 0. In that case, we can do iterations of the while loop where i doesn't move forward, so its not exactly O(n)

If the lps array is incrementing like [1,2,3,4,5,6,0]. If we fail to match at index 6, j gets updated to 5, and then 4, and then 3.... and etc and we effectively go through m extra iterations (assuming all mismatch). This can occur at every step.

so it would look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j >=0; j--)  {
    }
}
```

and to put all the possible i j combinations aka states would require a n*m array so wouldn't the runtime be O(n*m).

So is my reading of the code wrong, or the runtime analysis of the for loop wrong, or my example is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, now that I think about it. It is O(n+m). Just visualized it as two windows shifting.

Comment: As `n` is greater than or equal to  `m`, `O(n+m) = O(n)`